# Is it possible to provide the VMware workstation vm's service out to Internet?

Tags: vmware-workstation, nat

What should I set in the

I installed a VMware Workstation on my Windows Server(it own a public IP: `120.3.21.5`). and I created a vm from VMware Workstation.

The vm use VMware Workstation's vmnet8 network(`NAT` type), its IP address is `192.168.141.10`, the bellow is vmnet8's settings:

[image]

I have a requirement, how can I set, then I can access the Windows Server's public IP address, then I can access vm?

By detail, in the Windows Server I can access the vm's IP address `192.168.141.10`, it give a web service.

but I want to through the `120.3.21.5:1234` (public IP + port) to access the vm's web service. is it possible in the VMware Workstation configuration or configure the Windows Server to realize it? I know some NAT technology, but I don't know how to do it in there.

Comment: I don't believe you can remotely access a Workstation VM.  You need ESXi and VCenter in order to accomplish what you want.  You would be able to access your VCenter VMs with Workstation and/or the VSphere web client.  Those settings are simply the network adapter settings for the VM, outside of running software within the VM to remotely access it, none of those settings will allow you to remotely manage the VM.

Comment: Use the port forward option in your screenshot. Port forward port 80 to your VMs IP address 192.168.141.10.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP...

Comment: @Ramhound VMware Workstation comes with hostd, just like ESXi.  You can connect to shared Workstation VMs just like you can connect to VMs from ESXi.

Comment: @jamesdlin I use the port forward works fine, but the VM's emulated router/switches can not use my local pc to open its terminal. because the port did not forward.